# Pydev and vrapper: Whitespaces in empty lines

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, indentation, auto-indent

I am using PyDev with the vrapper plugin for Python development.

The problem is when I have workflows like the flowing:

```
if True:
    print "something"<Return>
    <Return>
    print "some more"<Return
```

Then line number 3 contains white spaces instead of an empty line which violates the PEP8 rule (pylint complains). Any ideas?

This the relevant part of my `.vrapperrc`.

```
set tabstop=8
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use the PyDev code formatter to automatically fix that for you.

I.e.: in preferences > pydev > editor > save actions enable 'auto-format editor contents before saving' and in preferences > pydev > editor > code style > code formatter make sure that 'right trim lines' is enabled.

Comment: Actually that is all activated.

Comment: So, when you save the file, aren't those white spaces removed?

Comment: Humm...strange... If you manually do Ctrl+Shift+F, does it work? Do you have some error in your error log? Maybe the vrapper plugin is doing something there (it may be nice asking the vrapper maintainer if it overrides something there, as this definitely works in plain PyDev).

Comment: I had to also enable PyDev/Editor/CodeStyle/CodeFormatter/ "Use autopep8.py for code formatting?"